# Обновление значений вложенного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть условный список с вложениями, пусть это будут рецепты `recipes = [['Яблоко','Слива','Кунжут'],['Вода','Соль','Летучая мышь']].`
Возможно ли:

1. Добавлять значения во вложенный список (т.е чтобы в элементе списка было не 3 а >3 значений)
2. Возможно ли обновлять значения вложенного списка.

Либо, может для таких задач подойдёт альтернативный вариант хранения данных?
Я думал про словарь, но там ключи не могут дублироваться, насколько мне известно.

Comment: Это рецепт того самого супа, который китайский дед поел осенью 2019?

Comment: @Xander, да пытаемся обучить ИИ на создание того самого супа перебирая известные кулинарии продукты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да:

```
recipes = [
        ['Яблоко','Слива','Кунжут'],
        ['Вода','Соль','Летучая мышь']
]

recipes[0][0] = 'Вода'
recipes[1].append("Яблоко")

print(recipes)
```

вывод:

```
[['Вода', 'Слива', 'Кунжут'], ['Вода', 'Соль', 'Летучая мышь', 'Яблоко']]
```

Comment: Вот про [index].append даже не подумал. Спасибо, я думаю это должно помочь. Попробую применить к своей задаче.